# I want pie - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm a portion of space or land
>
> I can be a solvable equation
>
> Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,
>
> A mask on the outside
>
> Won't show within
>
> So look around, I'm not hard to come by

**What am I?**

Hint:

> I would make all posted answers fall under me

Comment: is it a circle, or like an area of a circle

Comment: This question has had many answers posted, none of which has been accepted as correct.  The question may need refinement or additional lines to help to narrow down the correct answer.  As it is, the question seems too broad.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, sorry I have edited it!

Comment: Everybody. Who doesn't want pie?

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Circle

I'm a portion of space

> Circle is a shape in geometry.

Or a solvable equation

> Not sure. Is it area =
>  $π$ $*$ $r$<sup>$2$</sup>

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> To calculate area, it needs Pi

A mask on the outside
Won't show within

> Can be a cover.

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> There are many things around us in circle form.

Comment: Fixed the equation for you

Comment: Definitely the right direction, but not the exact answer I had in mind while I wrote it

Comment: Graphically, the equation of a circle is `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`.  For example, plotting `x^2 + y^2 = 16` will result in a circle with radius of 4.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Sphere or semi-sphere

I'm a portion of space

> Planets generally are found in spherical shape if you are referring to the Space.

Or a solvable equation

> Area of a sphere $\,=4\cdot\pi\cdot r^2$.
>  
>  Volume of a sphere $\,=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot r^3$.

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> To calculate area and volume, it needs Pi

A mask on the outside
Won't show within

> Can be a cover.

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> There are many things around us in sphere form.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are,

> Phase

I'm a portion of space

> phase space

Or a solvable equation

> 1-D case for phase space is line(so its solvable equation)

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> For higher dimensions it may need π

A mask on the outside
Won't show within

> No idea about this

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> like "phase" we go through(I am in my "**** the savings,lets go shopping" phase)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Donut

I'm a portion of space

> It is.

Or a solvable equation

> Definitely its volume is calculated using 2πRr^2

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> It needs pie to calculate whether its area or volume.

A mask on the outside
Won't show within

> They never told me what they put inside in it.

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> There are so many outlets out there where you can buy donut.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the answer is

> angle

I'm a portion of space:

> an angle is a portion of space.

or a solvable equation:

> the equation to find the angle between two points is 
>  atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> PI is used in the above formula. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-a-line-and-the-horizontal-axis)

A mask on the outside

> you only see the "outline" of the angle, it's external borders.

Won't show within

> same as above, you can't see the actual angle on the inside, but only the outline that it creates

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> angles are everywhere around us

Answer (score 0):

You might be:

> A sine function

I'm a portion of space

> You are one of the basics of physics in the universe

Or a solvable equation

> Sine functions are solvable

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> Without Pi sine functions are hard while not working with pie

A mask on the outside

> Outside of the brackets there is the sin sign? (sin(3*pi))

Won't show within

> It isn't always clear how the sine works? (not sure about this)

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> Well any wave there is, you can lead back to a sine function

Answer (score 0):

I'd have said

> A circumference

But then I changed my mind in something a bit more... lateral:

> The radius

I'm a portion of space

> The is a portion of space. Does not necessarily need to be 3D

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> You want a PI to calculate circumference or circle area

A mask on the outside

> A radius defines a certain circumference

Won't show within

> Having a hard time on this, but could be related to the circumference

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> You can look around in a certain radius, also a radius is the bone of the forearm on the thumb side, which a lot of people normally have before them :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are a:

> Cylinder.

I'm a portion of space:

> Yes you are.

Or a solvable equation:

> For sure.

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie:

> When you bake a pie you put it in a baking tray which usually is cylindric shaped.

Comment: This is basically like [this answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/i-want-pie-what-am-i/42086#42086).

Comment: Since when a cylinder is like a sphere or a semi-sphere?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Square?

I'm a portion of space

> Square as a geometric figure

Or a solvable equation

> Square equation

Yet I'm picky and might want a pie,

> Square [Area] of circle = Pi*R^2

A mask on the outside

Won't show within

So look around, I'm not hard to come by

> Squares are everywhere :)